# Comparing two matrices of different size to get common elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have matrix `A` size 100x100 and matrix `B` with size 200x200. I want to check whether each element in `A` is found in `B` or not and return a vector of common elements. So for example if the first element in `A` (1,1) is '10' then will check if `B` has an element '10' or not, if yes then will be added to the resulted common elements vector. So if anyone could please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
[C, ia, ib] = intersect(A,B);
```

`C` is the common elements vector, `ia` contains the indices of `A` and `ib` contains the indices of `B`, such that `C = A(ia)` and `C = B(ib)`. If you don't want indices, simply use:

```
C = intersect(A,B);
```

To search for every elements in `A` matrix in `B` matrix You can convert them to row vectors as follows:

```
A1 = reshape(A, 1, length(A));
B1 = reshape(B, 1, length(B));
```

And then use `intersect`.

Comment: @billy_chapters I didn't notice that OP wants for matrix, updated, thanks